# How do I put requirements on the equality of abstract member types

Tags: scala, type-members

I want my trait `Outer` to have two abstract member types `Inner1` and `Inner2`. I want `Inner2` to have abstract member type `Inner1` also. I want to put a requirement that `Outer#Inner1` is equal to `Inner2#Inner1`. What is the most conviniet way to do this? So far I have

```
trait HaveInner1 {
  type Inner1
}

trait Outer {
  type Inner1
  type Inner2 <: HaveInner1

  //    require Inner1 == Inner2#Inner1;
  def ?[T](implicit v: T): T = v
  implicit var ev: Inner2#Inner1 =:= Inner1 = ?[Inner2#Inner1 =:= Inner1]
}
```

The last two statements is not that pretty. Are there more idiomatic way to the same things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trait HaveInner1 {
  type Inner1
}

trait Outer /*extends HaveInner1*/ { outer =>
  type Inner1
  type Inner2 <: HaveInner1 { type Inner1 = outer.Inner1 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that `outer` is not neccesary if I use: `type Inner2 <: HaveInner1 { type Inner1 = Outer.this.Inner1 }`.

Comment: Would you please give a couple of terms for me to google: how do we call such expressions as {type Inner1 = outer.Inner1 } in Scala? The closest thing I've found is existential types, but it seems we can't add here `forSome'.